# SVG icons: Styling using CSS based on context

Tags: css, svg, icons

is it possible to style paths of SVG icons using CSS **based on their context**?

My SVG icon consists of 2 paths:

```
<g id="shape-codepen"> 
    <path class="outer-ring"  d="..."></path> 
    <path class="inner-logo"  d="..."></path> 
</g>
```

I use them in HTML as follow:

```
<svg class="shape-codepen"><use xlink:href="#shape-codepen"></use></svg>
<svg class="shape-codepen-red"><use xlink:href="#shape-codepen"></use></svg>
```

Basic styles:

```
.outer-ring { fill: #999; }
.inner-logo { fill: #666; }
```

But I want to change the partial color of the second one as it is in a different context, i.e.

```
.shape-codepen-red .outer-ring { fill: #f00; }
```

But is doesn't work.

**Here is a simple pencode illustration my problem:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZVGgv

**Is it possible to change partially color of a path of an icon based on it's context? How?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No...you can't access the internal parts like that. You need two `use` elements. One for the ring, and a second for the inner shape.

Then address them separately.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JXprwm)

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.red .red {
  fill: red;
}
.blue .blue {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg class="hide">
  <defs>
    <g id="shape-codepen-ring">
      <path class="outer-ring" d="M50,0C22.385,0,0,22.385,0,50c0,27.615,22.385,50,50,50c27.614,0,50-22.385,50-50C100,22.385,77.615,0,50,0z M50,91.789
  C26.958,91.789,8.212,73.042,8.212,50C8.212,26.958,26.958,8.212,50,8.212c23.042,0,41.788,18.747,41.788,41.789
  C91.788,73.042,73.042,91.789,50,91.789z"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="shape-codepen-shape">
      <path class="inner-logo" d="M80.893,40.234c-0.006-0.039-0.016-0.076-0.022-0.115c-0.013-0.075-0.027-0.15-0.046-0.223
  c-0.012-0.044-0.028-0.086-0.042-0.128c-0.021-0.065-0.042-0.13-0.068-0.193c-0.018-0.044-0.039-0.088-0.059-0.13
  c-0.028-0.06-0.057-0.119-0.09-0.175c-0.024-0.042-0.051-0.083-0.076-0.124c-0.036-0.055-0.073-0.109-0.112-0.161
  c-0.029-0.039-0.06-0.078-0.091-0.115c-0.042-0.049-0.086-0.098-0.132-0.143c-0.035-0.036-0.069-0.072-0.106-0.104
  c-0.049-0.044-0.099-0.086-0.15-0.127c-0.04-0.031-0.079-0.062-0.12-0.091c-0.016-0.01-0.029-0.023-0.044-0.033L51.474,19.531
  c-0.893-0.595-2.055-0.595-2.947,0L20.267,38.371c-0.015,0.01-0.028,0.023-0.044,0.033c-0.042,0.029-0.081,0.06-0.12,0.091
  c-0.052,0.041-0.102,0.083-0.15,0.127c-0.037,0.032-0.071,0.068-0.106,0.104c-0.046,0.045-0.09,0.094-0.132,0.143
  c-0.031,0.038-0.062,0.077-0.092,0.115c-0.039,0.052-0.076,0.106-0.111,0.161c-0.027,0.041-0.052,0.082-0.076,0.124
  c-0.033,0.057-0.062,0.115-0.09,0.175c-0.021,0.042-0.042,0.086-0.06,0.13c-0.026,0.063-0.047,0.128-0.068,0.193
  c-0.014,0.042-0.029,0.084-0.042,0.128c-0.02,0.073-0.032,0.148-0.046,0.223c-0.006,0.039-0.016,0.076-0.021,0.115
  c-0.016,0.114-0.024,0.229-0.024,0.346V59.42c0,0.117,0.009,0.233,0.024,0.348c0.005,0.038,0.015,0.077,0.021,0.114
  c0.014,0.075,0.027,0.149,0.046,0.223c0.012,0.043,0.028,0.086,0.042,0.128c0.021,0.065,0.042,0.13,0.068,0.195
  c0.018,0.044,0.039,0.086,0.06,0.129c0.028,0.06,0.058,0.118,0.09,0.177c0.024,0.041,0.049,0.082,0.076,0.122
  c0.035,0.056,0.072,0.109,0.111,0.161c0.029,0.041,0.061,0.078,0.092,0.115c0.042,0.049,0.086,0.098,0.132,0.144
  c0.035,0.036,0.069,0.071,0.106,0.104c0.048,0.044,0.099,0.086,0.15,0.127c0.039,0.031,0.078,0.062,0.12,0.091
  c0.016,0.01,0.029,0.023,0.044,0.032l28.259,18.84c0.446,0.297,0.96,0.447,1.474,0.447c0.513,0,1.027-0.149,1.473-0.447
  l28.259-18.84c0.015-0.009,0.028-0.022,0.044-0.032c0.042-0.029,0.081-0.06,0.12-0.091c0.051-0.041,0.102-0.083,0.15-0.127
  c0.037-0.033,0.071-0.068,0.106-0.104c0.046-0.046,0.09-0.095,0.132-0.144c0.031-0.037,0.062-0.075,0.091-0.115
  c0.04-0.052,0.076-0.105,0.112-0.161c0.025-0.041,0.051-0.081,0.076-0.122c0.033-0.059,0.062-0.117,0.09-0.177
  c0.02-0.042,0.041-0.085,0.059-0.129c0.026-0.065,0.047-0.13,0.068-0.195c0.014-0.042,0.03-0.085,0.042-0.128
  c0.02-0.074,0.033-0.148,0.046-0.223c0.006-0.037,0.016-0.076,0.022-0.114c0.014-0.115,0.023-0.231,0.023-0.348V40.581
  C80.916,40.464,80.907,40.348,80.893,40.234z M52.657,26.707l20.817,13.877l-9.298,6.221l-11.519-7.706V26.707z M47.343,26.707
  v12.393l-11.518,7.706l-9.299-6.221L47.343,26.707z M24.398,45.554L31.046,50l-6.648,4.446V45.554z M47.343,73.294L26.525,59.417
  l9.299-6.219l11.518,7.704V73.294z M50,56.286L40.603,50L50,43.715L59.397,50L50,56.286z M52.657,73.294V60.902l11.519-7.704
  l9.298,6.219L52.657,73.294z M75.602,54.447L68.955,50l6.647-4.446V54.447z"></path>
    </g>
    <path id="shape-twitter" d="M100.001,17.942c-3.681,1.688-7.633,2.826-11.783,3.339
 c4.236-2.624,7.49-6.779,9.021-11.73c-3.965,2.432-8.354,4.193-13.026,5.146C80.47,10.575,75.138,8,69.234,8
 c-11.33,0-20.518,9.494-20.518,21.205c0,1.662,0.183,3.281,0.533,4.833c-17.052-0.884-32.168-9.326-42.288-22.155
 c-1.767,3.133-2.778,6.773-2.778,10.659c0,7.357,3.622,13.849,9.127,17.65c-3.363-0.109-6.525-1.064-9.293-2.651
 c-0.002,0.089-0.002,0.178-0.002,0.268c0,10.272,7.072,18.845,16.458,20.793c-1.721,0.484-3.534,0.744-5.405,0.744
 c-1.322,0-2.606-0.134-3.859-0.379c2.609,8.424,10.187,14.555,19.166,14.726c-7.021,5.688-15.867,9.077-25.48,9.077
 c-1.656,0-3.289-0.102-4.895-0.297C9.08,88.491,19.865,92,31.449,92c37.737,0,58.374-32.312,58.374-60.336
 c0-0.92-0.02-1.834-0.059-2.743C93.771,25.929,97.251,22.195,100.001,17.942L100.001,17.942z"></path>
    <g id="shape-youtube">
      <path class="youtube" d="M98.77,27.492c-1.225-5.064-5.576-8.799-10.811-9.354C75.561,16.818,63.01,15.993,50.514,16
  c-12.495-0.007-25.045,0.816-37.446,2.139c-5.235,0.557-9.583,4.289-10.806,9.354C0.522,34.704,0.5,42.574,0.5,50.001
  c0,7.426,0,15.296,1.741,22.509c1.224,5.061,5.572,8.799,10.807,9.352c12.399,1.32,24.949,2.145,37.446,2.14
  c12.494,0.005,25.047-0.817,37.443-2.14c5.234-0.555,9.586-4.291,10.81-9.352c1.741-7.213,1.753-15.083,1.753-22.509
  S100.51,34.704,98.77,27.492 M67.549,52.203L43.977,64.391c-2.344,1.213-4.262,0.119-4.262-2.428V38.036
  c0-2.548,1.917-3.644,4.262-2.429l23.572,12.188C69.896,49.008,69.896,50.992,67.549,52.203"></path>
    </g>

  </defs>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon red">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-codepen-shape"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#shape-codepen-ring" class="red"></use>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon blue">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-codepen-shape"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#shape-codepen-ring" class="blue"></use>
</svg>
```

Note:  Chris Coyier actually covers this in his [**Lodge SVG**](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/) course of videos